# How to add a Map<String, Person> in an entity class?

Tags: jpa, dictionary, eclipselink, entity-relationship

I want to add a mapping as

```
Map<String, Person> personMap;
```

inside an entity class, where `Person` is the entity. The `Map` is to identify the exact `Person` corresponding to the `String` (let it be a nickname of that person). The same person may have different names and whenever any of the names is given, the same `Person` has to be found.

Persistance API used is JPA and the provider is EclipseLink. What annotation should I use and how?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per section 2.7 of JSR-317, if the value of the Map is an entity (which is your case) a join table is created and then a OneToMany / ManyToOne annotation should be used.

As for the key, if it is a Basic Type, the @MapKeyColumn can be used to customize the mapping column of the key. So here is my take on your example:

```
@OneToMany
@MapKeyColumn(name="person_nickname")
Map<String, Person> personMap;
```

EDITED:

After some testing, the following seems to work pretty well:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="<name_of_join_table>")
@MapKeyColumn(name="<name_of_map_key_in_table>")
Map<String, Person> personMap;
```

The above generates a join table with three fields: one for the mapping holder id, one for the key and one for the value.

Comment: Works great, but auto fetch doesn't work for me, when reading mapped items into Map.